# Socket.io package not installing in window 7 Node.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, node.js, socket.io

Hi Friends i am tryeng to install socket.io module using **npm install socket.io**. Its not working  i got following error:

```
npm WARN package.json an-hybrid-app@0.1.0 No README.md file found!
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.11
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.11
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/options
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/options
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander

> ws@0.4.25 install E:\chat_\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.i
o-client\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

CreateProcessW: The system cannot find the file specified.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'E:\chat_\nodejs\node_module
s\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\active-x-obfuscator\node_
modules\zeparser'
npm ERR! error rolling back  socket.io-client@0.9.11 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir
'E:\chat_\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modul
es\active-x-obfuscator\node_modules\zeparser']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'E:\\chat_\\nodejs\\node_modules\\socket.io\
\node_modules\\socket.io-client\\node_modules\\active-x-obfuscator\\node_modules
\\zeparser' }
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EPERM, readdir 'E:\chat_\nodejs\node_modules\
socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\active-x-obfuscator\node_mo
dules\zeparser\benchmark.html'
npm ERR! error rolling back  socket.io@0.9.13 { [Error: EPERM, readdir 'E:\chat_
\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\active
-x-obfuscator\node_modules\zeparser\benchmark.html']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 50,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'E:\\chat_\\nodejs\\node_modules\\socket.io\
\node_modules\\socket.io-client\\node_modules\\active-x-obfuscator\\node_modules
\\zeparser\\benchmark.html' }
npm ERR! ws@0.4.25 install: `(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)`
npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)"` failed wi
th 127
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ws@0.4.25 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ws package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ws
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "socket.io"
npm ERR! cwd E:\chat_\nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.18
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'E:\chat_\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modul
es\socket.io-client\node_modules\active-x-obfuscator\node_modules\zeparser\bench
mark.html'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod  ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "socket.io"
npm ERR! cwd E:\chat_\nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.18
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.2
npm ERR! path E:\chat_\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\active-x-obfuscator\node_modules\zeparser\benchmark.html
```

npm ERR! fstream_path E:\chat_\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket
.io-client\node_modules\active-x-obfuscator\node_modules\zeparser\benchmark.html

```
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     E:\chat_\nodejs\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I am new in node.js please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lays in the ws package. It just can't find `cmd.exe`. Add to your `PATH` environment the path to %SYSTEMROOT%\System32 or C:\Windows\System32

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all the required software to run `node-gyp`:

- https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp

You can also configure version of Visual Studio used by `node-gyp` via an environment variable so you can avoid having to set the `--msvs_version=2012` property every time you do an npm install.

Examples:

- set `GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2012` for Visual Studio 2012
- set `GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2013e` (the 'e' stands for 'express edition')

For the full list see 
 - https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.29/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/MSVSVersion.py#L209-294

This is still painful for Windows users of NodeJS as it assumes you have a copy of Visual Studio installed and many end users will never have this. So I'm lobbying Joyent to the encourage them to include web sockets as part of CORE node and also to possible ship a GNU gcc compiler as part of NodeJS install so we can permanently fix this problem.

Feel free to add your vote at:

- https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8005#issuecomment-50545326